# export model data to excel mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@model SA.MarketingManager.WebClient.Areas.Reports.Models.ViewReportModel
@{
    Layout = "~/CustomViews/lennoxcap.net/Shared/_DealerLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 9px;" id="results">
        <h3  style="background-color: #CC0000; color: #fff; font-size: 1.5em;">
            Customer Survey Report</h3>
        @if (Model.Report.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table id="SurveyResponse" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="header">
                        <td>
                            Dealer #
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            District
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            TM
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Survey Code
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            First Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Last Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Address
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            City
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            State
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Postal Code
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Phone
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Mail Sent
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Email Sent
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{bool alternate = false;}
                    @foreach (var tr in Model.Report)
                    {
                        <tr @(alternate ? "class=alternate" : "")>
                            <td>
                                @tr.DealerId
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @tr.District
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.TM
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.SurveyCode
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.FirstName
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.LastName
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.Address
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.City
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.State
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.PostalCode
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.Phone
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.MailSent
                            </td>
                            <td>@tr.DateCompleted
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                           alternate = !alternate;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>There are no records to display</text>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Export Data" class="PremierSubmitButton" />
       </p>
    </div>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult CustomerReport()
    { 
        ViewReportModel model = new ViewReportModel();
            var query = (from u in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.LennoxSurveyResponses
                            join c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingListEntries on u.SurveyCode equals c.SurveyCode
                            join cl in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingLists on c.MailingListId equals cl.MailingListId
                            join ch in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.Channels on cl.ChannelId equals ch.ChannelId
                            join cg in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups on ch.ChannelGroupId equals cg.ChannelGroupId
                            //let con = ch.Contacts.FirstOrDefault()
                            where ch.OrganizationId == 8
                            //&& con.ContactTypeId == ContactTypeConstants.TMId
                            //select new ReportDetails() { SurveyResponse = u, MailingListEntry = c, Channel = cl.Channel, Contact = con }); 
                            select new ReportDetails{   DealerId = ch.ExternalChannelId,
                                                        District = ch.ChannelAMSData.District,
                                                        TM = cg.Name,
                                                        SurveyCode = u.SurveyCode,
                                                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                                        LastName = c.LastName,
                                                        Address = c.Address1,
                                                        City = c.City,
                                                        State = c.State,
                                                        PostalCode = c.PostalCode,
                                                        Email = c.Email,
                                                        Phone = c.Phone,
                                                        MailSent = c.LetterDate,
                                                        DateCompleted = c.EmailDate});
               model.Report = query;
               return View("CustomerReport", model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CustomerReport(ViewReportModel model)
    {
        var query = (from u in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.LennoxSurveyResponses
                     join c in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingListEntries on u.SurveyCode equals c.SurveyCode
                     join cl in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.MailingLists on c.MailingListId equals cl.MailingListId
                     join ch in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.Channels on cl.ChannelId equals ch.ChannelId
                     join cg in SessionHandler.CurrentContext.ChannelGroups on ch.ChannelGroupId equals cg.ChannelGroupId
                     where ch.OrganizationId == 8
                     select new ReportDetails
                     {
                         DealerId = ch.ExternalChannelId,
                         District = ch.ChannelAMSData.District,
                         TM = cg.Name,
                         SurveyCode = u.SurveyCode,
                         FirstName = c.FirstName,
                         LastName = c.LastName,
                         Address = c.Address1,
                         City = c.City,
                         State = c.State,
                         PostalCode = c.PostalCode,
                         Email = c.Email,
                         Phone = c.Phone,
                         MailSent = c.LetterDate,
                         DateCompleted = c.EmailDate
                     });
        model.Report = query;
        return new Utilities.ExcelResult<ViewReportModel>(
            ControllerContext,
            "~/ExcelReport.aspx",
            "CustomerReport.xls",
            model
            );
    }
```

My model ReportsModel.cs

```
public class ReportDetails 
{
    public string DealerId { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string TM { get; set; }
    public string SurveyCode { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MailSent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
}

public class ViewReportModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ReportDetails> Report { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little blog post about this here : http://landokal.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/asp-net-mvc-export-to-excel-trick/

Essentially, what you could do is, create a button that sent the contents of one of the elements on your page and assigned it to a property on your model, therefore everytime you exported that view, your Export method could check the model property instead of rendering the view directly.

Also in the post are some code samples how to do a basic export to excel in MVC if you don't want to go the other route.

Comment: Hey slandau, i have a question. If I my view data in a model, how would i be able to pass it to your ExcelResult class.public ActionResult CustomerReport(ViewReportModel model)
        {
            
            return new Utilities.ExcelResult<ModelBase>(
                ControllerContext,
                "Export.aspx",
                "ExcelExport",
                model
                );
        } I can't find ModelBase. Using your solution, I should be able to make this work.

Comment: Instead of passing in "Export.aspx", you want to switch out that parameter for the string that you are saving back into your model of the HTML you save.

Comment: This is what i have public ActionResult [HttpPost]CustomerReport(ViewReportModel model)
        {
            
            return new Utilities.ExcelResult<MarketingManager.WebClient.Models.M>(
                ControllerContext,
                "Reports/Views/CustomerReport.cshtml",
                "ExcelExport",
                model.Report
                );
        } Its giving me an error on ModelBase and model.Report.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing in a view there if you're doing it the trick way. You should be saving the results of the view to a property on your model, and then passing in that string.

Comment: I changed it to public ActionResult CustomerReport(ViewReportModel model)
        {
            
            return new Utilities.ExcelResult<ViewReportModel>(
                ControllerContext,
                model.Report.ToString(),
                "ExcelExport",
                model
                );
        } Now i get an error on return new ExcelResult<ViewReportModel>..Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Debug through, what's your Report.ToString() giving you?

Comment: All i get is the query string, not the html. I guess when you said to store the html value in a property, thats what i need to do. How would i store the html in a property?

Comment: That should be completely outlined in my blog post. Using AJAX from your view, once its rendered, you can make a call back to an action method, set that value on your property, and then have it stored.

Comment: Hi slandau, i made some progress. Now the spreadsheet opens but without any data. In the ActionResult, i am using return new Utilities.ExcelResult<ViewReportModel>(
                ControllerContext,
                "~/ExcelReport.aspx",
                "CustomerReport.xls",
                model
                ); The model is empty. I have a IENumerable property in my model called Report. Could i pass this instead of just model?

Comment: If your view contains all of the data on it (and it's not updated dynamically), you can pass it like that, yes. However, what do you mean your model is empty? Does your view inherit this model?

Comment: Yes it does. I populate model.Report using var object. So, i was wondering if i could pass model.Report instead of just an instance of my model. When i tried doing that, it didn't like it -> model.Report

Comment: Just did it..let me know if you need any clarification on what i have done with my code. Thanks!!

Comment: Okay well your setting model.Report but never using it?

Comment: Since my model.Report is a IENumerable, it gives me an error when i try to use it. Cannot convert from Models.ReportModel to ViewReportModel.

Comment: Are you using the code that I had in my blog post in your ExcelResult class as well, to check if your passing in a string or an .aspx path?

Comment: nope..should i be using it? where should i put that? in the same controller where i have my ActionResult?

Comment: Make sure your ExcelResult class looks identical to mine, and then pass in your Model.Report instead of the view name, and tell me what happens

Comment: I can't pass Model.Report since its IEnumerable where the second parameter on ExcelResult is a string (i.e. string viewPath).

Comment: It should never be Innumerable if you're following the directions in the blog post. It should be HTML text

Comment: sorry to make this longer. You have described two ways to do this in your blog. The first one, if i look at return new ExcelResult<ModelBase>
                (
                    ControllerContext,
                    "Export.aspx",
                    "ExcelExport",
                    myModel
                );
what is your myModel? How do you populate this? If i am not wrong, you can produce excel report with ExcelResult class and the return above, correct? I have the exact identical copy of your ExcelResult class. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: Yes you can. However, if your view is filled with data dynamically, then you will need to do it the other way. If you pass a string into that method in place of Export.aspx, then myModel never gets used. Make sense?